# How to call Ctrl-F of IE9 and highlight few words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to call Ctrl-F or open Search tool of IE9 on click of some element.

**I want to open a new browser on click of some hyperlink and highlight few words there.**

I have a code of

```
function openLink(thiis, keywords){ //keywords is a comma seperated words.
    var val = $(thiis).text();
    window.open(val,'_blank',"toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width=1000,height=650,left=10,right=1230");
}
```

Its opening my new window. Nothing new.

I am able to highlight texts successfully on my same browser but not in new window.

To highlight texts on same window please check my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaikratsingh/8Lbjnnog/6/)

Refrence - [hilite](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/)

I did some googling before posting my question here but could not find any satisfactory answer.

Anyone!!! How can I open a new browser window, call its ctrl-f, put my text there and highlight them on the page using jquery or javascript anything.

Comment: You can't do that. JavaScript rarely can influence the user interface of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

your current highlighting solution does not use the browsers `Ctrl+F` search in page functionality. it is a javascript that changes the style and dom so that the search term gets highlighted.

to do this on a other page, you would need to include the highlighting script on the opening page. than after opening the new window directly set a variable within the popup page. the popup page can later read its value and highlight the content accordingly.

base page:

```
var windowHandle = window.open(…);
windowHandle.highlightTerm = 'WHAT IS TO BE HIGHLIGHTED';
```

popup page:

```
var myHilitor = new Hilitor("content");
myHilitor.apply(highlightTerm);
```

*have in mind that both pages will have to be on the same domain*

Comment: Thanks for reply @dreamlab. Yeah, my highlighted code is not for Ctrl+F search. It is just to highlight text on same browser. Though, I tried your example but dint work. Its saying..."
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'highlight'". I tried within and out of my localhost domain too.

Comment: did you declare the `highlight()` method in the popup page?

Comment: the issue probably is that you call the function before the popup page has loaded. i modiefied the answer. now you set a variable in the popup page, wich Hilitor uses.

Comment: Actually, I have no control over the code of popup page. So I think, its not doable for my case cause I can open any URL.

Comment: you are right. if you are loading external pages from a website in a browser it is not possible. although if you are building an app, that has a webview or a browser extension it is possible.